# Azure DevOps dashboard configurations

Tags: azure-devops

we are an operational support team and we support 3 different Salesforce systems and 1 amazon connect system. i need to create dashboard for reporting bugs, PBIs in a sprint to report velocity, throughput and display the number of work items according to state. this needs to be broken down into 3 different salesforce systems and amazon connect. we have a tag for amazon connect incidents and  1 tag for all salesforce incidents. im new to ADO, any advise is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there's no built-in widget that can meet all of your requirements. But you can use several widgets to track them.

There is a widget called **Velocity** in Dashboards that you can use to track a team's capacity to deliver work sprint after sprint. You can select a specific work item type that you want to track. Please note that it tracks the velocity for a single team, not multiple teams.
You can refer to [the official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=azure-devops#configure-the-velocity-widget) for more details.

But the Velocity widget can't filter the work items by tags or area path. In addition, you could create a new widget called **Chart for work items** to track work items by tags. It adds a tile to display a progress or trend chart that builds off a shared work item query. You could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?view=azure-devops#add-a-chart-widget-to-a-dashboard) for more details.
So, firstly, you need to create a query under shared folder.

For example, I want to track Bug with the tag: "tag". I can create a query using the filters like:

Work item types=Bug

Tags Contains tag

Please remember to save the query under Shared Queries folder.

You could refer to [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) to create a query.

After creating a shared query, you can choose the query in the widget. And choose State in Group by column. The chart will show the number the specific work item with the tag according to state.